# Populating numbered class names in css sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

I have

```
.cover0,.cover1,.cover2
{
    opacity : .50;
    filter  : alpha(opacity=50); /* IE<9 */
    cursor  : default;
}
```

in my style sheet.

I need to add classes up to `.cover100`.

Is there any way to do it apart from hardcoding it?

Something like a `for` loop in JavaScript.. Can be done something like that in a style sheet?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need 100 identical classes?

Comment: Why not assign a single class to all the elements that currently use `.cover0`, `.cover1` etc.

Comment: Got to agree with Teemu and NTL.  Unless each of those 100 classes are different there is no need for them.  A single class applied any element would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SASS is the best option.

Though you can use a [**Attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

* meaning the class *contains*

**NOTE**: this will match other classes containing `cover`, ie `covered`, etc

```css
[class*=cover] {

    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
      opacity : .50;
      filter  : alpha(opacity=50); /* IE<9 */
      cursor  : default;
  }
```

```html
<div class="cover extras">
</div>
<div class="cover">
</div>
<div class="befores cover">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [SASS](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while). It's easy:

```
.cover-0 {
  opacity: .50;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* IE<9 */
  cursor: default;
}

@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .cover-#{$i} {
    @extend .cover-0;
  }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/6a945392481c3d2bab6e8e7969e5bfb2

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with pure CSS.

However, you could look into a CSS preprocessor, e.g. [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#):

```
.generate-columns(4);

.generate-columns(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  .column-@{i} {
    width: (@i * 100% / @n);
  }
  .generate-columns(@n, (@i + 1));
}

// Result:

.column-1 {
  width: 25%;
}
.column-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
.column-3 {
  width: 75%;
}
.column-4 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Source](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature)